# SQL Server - Why does it allow me to insert blanks into a non-nullable column?

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a table in SQL Server with a column that is a varchar(50) and set as a non-null column. This column is not a primary key.

If I try to do a null insert, I get the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column. Column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

Which is expected.

I would expect the same to be true if I tried to insert a '' but for some reason it is allowing blanks without an issue. Why? How can I make the table not allow blanks into this specific column? I don't want a default value, I want the insert to fail the same way that a null fails.

Thank you

Comment: why?, because an empty string is an actual value, not a `NULL`, it's pretty straightforward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty string is something different from a `NULL` value. `NULL` really means not available, not known.

You can add a `CHECK` constraint to implement the functionality you are after:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_EmptyString CHECK  ( myCol <> '')
```

Comment: Could you use `NULLIF`? OP will probably run into spaces as well being not null. `LEN` would trim that for them. Would something like `constraint superNull check NULLIF(len(myCol), 0) IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 3):

> [I] would expect the same to be true if I tried to insert a '' but for some reason it is allowing blanks without an issue. Why?

Because an empty string is not a null!

If you want to stop empty strings, you could use a [check constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190377.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because an empty string is not a NULL value.

You can add a CHECK constraint on the table/column to get your desired result.

```
create table #a(name nvarchar(20))

alter table #a add check (name != '')
```

Incidentally, that check will also prevent strings of only spaces as well.

```
insert into #a(name) values ('')

insert into #a(name) values (' ')

insert into #a(name) values ('  ')

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__#a__________name__1CA18AD3". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.#a__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000BF04A", column 'name'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

EDIT: Constraint to allow a space-only insert.

```
ALTER TABLE #a ADD CHECK (name != '' or charindex(' ',name) = 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

> I would expect the same to be true if I tried to insert a ''

I want a steak, but vegetarian. IT MAKES NO SENSE - not in the term of "the same" (i.e. the same error) as null is not space.

Similar - ok. But then - there are cases a space may be wanted. Not ok with you? Why do you not set up a check constraint? That is the way to limit values to a particular value.

Comment: Not exactly sure if all caps saying it makes no sense is appropriate